# Does funnel stage of datastage need source tables have the same structure?

Tags: datastage

There are 2 source tables, and I use funnel to union them in datastage. But it reports that "The source and destination have differing nullability. [api/transfer_rep.C:199]", because the source tables have a field with different nullability.
Does funnel stage of datastage need source tables have exactly the same structure? Even if I used NVL function in the source select statement, it still reported the same error. Can somebody help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Clearly YES - they have to have identical structures

Check out the [KC](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZJPZ_11.5.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.ds.parjob.dev.doc/topics/c_deeref_Funnel_Stage.html):

> "meta data of all input data sets must be identical."

YOu could use a copy stage to adjust column names and nullability or a transformer if additional type adjustments are necessary.

Comment: Copy stage or transformer is no use, I try both, but still get the same error. Thanks all the same.

Comment: Well check it again - both (or all) input table definitions AND the output table definition

Comment: The source tables do have different nullability. But copy stage or transformer has no use. Is there an alternative way...

Comment: Why do you think it has no use? NullToEmpty, NullToValue are functions to change the nullability (plus changing the table definition)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, Metadata of sources should be same for Funnel stage.

Comment: Thanks. I have figured out another way instead of using Funnel stage.